# Helping me understand an example from herstein’s book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I’m new to algebra and I’m reading Herstein's book , this example seems to be wrong .
Isn’t it ?

If it’s not , can someone please explain it to me ?

Why did he do the multiplication from left to right rather right to left ?

[image]

The answer shouldn’t be like $(1    8   5   6   4   2  3)$?

Comment: It seems that the convention for multiplication is from left to right, rather then from right to left... so if you reverse you get the answer Herstein had in mind ... you answer is right by the way.

Comment: @NickyHekster But why would he do the multiplication from left to right ?

Comment: I would not know. Permutations can be seen as functions on a finite set and as with the composition of functions $f \circ g$, one starts with $g$ ... Does Herstein provide a definition anywhere in the book?

Comment: Thank you for your consideration though.

Comment: I think Herstein uses the maps on right convention throughout the book. So group homomorphisms are also written on the right of the argument and composed from left to right. You should also be aware that if ever you get around to using group theory software packages GAP or Magma, then they both compose permutations (and also linear maps) from left to right.

Comment: @DerekHolt thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: @DietrichBurde sure.sorry

Comment: @Negar I've seen both conventions. Just be aware that you might find either of them, I honestly prefer right to left as it is consitent with the convention for composition of maps.